# Ubuntu 17.10 periodically blocks networking connection

Tags: networking, dns, 17.10

I have installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop and am experiencing networking problems. Those occur periodically, somewhere every hour or so. At least that's when I notice them. The error shows, when I open the browser an search for a domain. The network connection then freezes for about 30 seconds before loading the page. nslookup and ping behave the same. IP traffic works, but DNS doesn't during that time.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10 with different desktops, but I run into the same error every time.

Where could I find the appropriate error log for this apparent network problem? I don't really know where to search for it. I checked `/var/log/syslog` and found that there are many NetworkManager entries. Still, yet this didn't bring me to solve the networking problem. What I also found out is an AAAA conflict that often occurs and is logged within `/var/log/syslog`.

Trail of the last 80 lines of /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus kernel: [ 1623.145160] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus wpa_supplicant[1038]: wlp3s0: Associated with 9c:c7:a6:ac:7a:37
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus wpa_supplicant[1038]: p2p-dev-wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.0939] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dbus-daemon[1992]: Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus wpa_supplicant[1038]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 9c:c7:a6:ac:7a:37 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus wpa_supplicant[1038]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 9c:c7:a6:ac:7a:37 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1129] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1130] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'MyHomeNetwork'.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1130] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1133] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1144] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 2401
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dbus-daemon[1992]: Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.secrets'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2401]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.10.11.79 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x74a2b1e8)
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2401]: DHCPACK of 10.10.11.79 from 10.10.11.1
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1695] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 10.10.11.79
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1695] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1696] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 10.10.11.1
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1696] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 864000
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1696] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '10.10.11.1'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 10.10.11.79.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1696] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   domain name 'fritz.box'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1696] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Registering new address record for 10.10.11.79 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1710] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1714] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1716] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', internal state 'managed')
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2401]: bound to 10.10.11.79 -- renewal in 331713 seconds.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821159.1765] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dbus[910]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus dbus[910]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec  9 13:05:59 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: get-updates transaction /321_cbebdcad from uid 1000 finished with success after 486ms
Dec  9 13:06:00 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: get-updates transaction /322_daacdecd from uid 1000 finished with success after 423ms
Dec  9 13:06:01 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::8e23:5238:4a0a:ba87.
Dec  9 13:06:01 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec  9 13:06:01 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Registering new address record for fe80::8e23:5238:4a0a:ba87 on wlp3s0.*.
Dec  9 13:06:01 lpt-myuser-asus systemd-resolved[1006]: Detected conflict on lpt-myuser-asus IN AAAA fe80::8e23:5238:4a0a:ba87
Dec  9 13:06:01 lpt-myuser-asus systemd-resolved[1006]: Hostname conflict, changing published hostname from 'lpt-myuser-asus' to 'lpt-myuser-asus10'.
Dec  9 13:06:02 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821162.8586] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec  9 13:06:02 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <warn>  [1512821162.8586] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): hostname is not a FQDN, it will be ignored
Dec  9 13:06:02 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821162.8596] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 2519
Dec  9 13:06:03 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2519]: XMT: Info-Request on wlp3s0, interval 920ms.
Dec  9 13:06:03 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::8e23:5238:4a0a:ba87.
Dec  9 13:06:03 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address 2a02:8071:3195:cd00:9a30:4c8:fa16:b2d9.
Dec  9 13:06:03 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Registering new address record for 2a02:8071:3195:cd00:9a30:4c8:fa16:b2d9 on wlp3s0.*.
Dec  9 13:06:03 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::8e23:5238:4a0a:ba87 on wlp3s0.
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2519]: XMT: Info-Request on wlp3s0, interval 1780ms.
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus avahi-daemon[913]: Registering new address record for 2a02:8071:3195:cd00:94a4:2cb1:941:b18b on wlp3s0.*.
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus dhclient[2519]: RCV: Reply message on wlp3s0 from fe80::9ec7:a6ff:feac:7a35.
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821164.9832] dhcp6 (wlp3s0):   nameserver 'fd00::9ec7:a6ff:feac:7a35'
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821164.9832] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821164.9854] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): client pid 2519 exited with status 0
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus NetworkManager[925]: <info>  [1512821164.9854] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus nm-dispatcher: req:2 'dhcp6-change' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Dec  9 13:06:04 lpt-myuser-asus nm-dispatcher: req:2 'dhcp6-change' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Dec  9 13:06:42 lpt-myuser-asus whoopsie[1184]: [13:06:42] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Dec  9 13:06:42 lpt-myuser-asus whoopsie[1184]: [13:06:42] offline
Dec  9 13:07:12 lpt-myuser-asus whoopsie[1184]: [13:07:12] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Dec  9 13:07:12 lpt-myuser-asus whoopsie[1184]: [13:07:12] online
Dec  9 13:08:56 lpt-myuser-asus dbus[910]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.AptXapianIndex' (using servicehelper)
Dec  9 13:08:56 lpt-myuser-asus dbus[910]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.AptXapianIndex'
Dec  9 13:09:30 lpt-myuser-asus dbus-daemon[1992]: Activating service name='org.kubuntu.DriverManager'
Dec  9 13:09:31 lpt-myuser-asus dbus-daemon[1992]: Successfully activated service 'org.kubuntu.DriverManager'
Dec  9 13:09:44 lpt-myuser-asus org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1992]: DriverManager_DBus::devices START
Dec  9 13:09:44 lpt-myuser-asus org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1992]: DriverManager_DBus::devices END
Dec  9 13:11:05 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /323_dccedcdb from uid 1000 finished with success after 7260ms
Dec  9 13:11:06 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: get-updates transaction /324_eaecbeca from uid 1000 finished with success after 1362ms
Dec  9 13:11:07 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: get-updates transaction /325_abccaeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 429ms
Dec  9 13:11:07 lpt-myuser-asus PackageKit: get-updates transaction /326_abedcbad from uid 1000 finished with success after 405ms
Dec  9 13:14:46 lpt-myuser-asus wpa_supplicant[1038]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 9c:c7:a6:ac:7a:37 [GTK=CCMP]
Dec  9 13:17:01 lpt-myuser-asus CRON[3363]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Any hint greatly appreciated!